# Keysight ADS layout error "port pin not connected to conductive part of design"

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, simulation, microwave, pcb-layers

I just designed a distributed element BPF using ADS and now I'm trying to put it into the layout to do an EM simulation. I created my distributed circuit using the dimensions of my components, then connected them using wires (zero length electrical connections) and added ports. The program gives me this error when I try to run the EM simulation: "At least one port pin or bondwire end is not fully connected to a conductive part of the design (see the layout processing report for details)."

Here is a picture of my distributed circuit outside of layout mode:
[image]
Here is a picture of my distributed circuit inside of layout mode:
[image: the two very thin in-series lines, the thick in-series line and the parallel wide lines are my components. the brighter red lines connecting them are wires. the arrows are ports 1 and 2.]
I checked that my components are on the conductive layer and my pins are on the conductive layer. (I think I did). When I click on conductive layer 1 my components highlight.

If anyone has familiarity with ADS would you have any suggestions for what issue I might be having? Any help would be greatly appreciated.